# What does "to get use of" mean?

Tags: meaning

Consider the following sentence:

> We got to make sure we **get the most use out of** our money, and out of
> our time.

From the context, I believe *to get use of* means the same as *to make use of*.
Is that correct?
I don't think I have heard *to get use of* before,
is it frequently used?

Comment: **The English is wrong**. We've got to make sure we get the most use out of our money...OR: We have to make sure....to get the most use out of something and make the most of something are different. But none of it is **good written style**.

Comment: I have heard 'get the use of' something plenty of times. You get the most use of something when you exploit it in the most efficient or productive manner.